# What is wrong with decoherence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, decoherence, open-quantum-systems, foundations

One possible explanation of the quantum to classical transition, or in other words of why we don't see macroscopic quantum effects naturally, is environment induced decoherence.

Basically, the system inevitably couples to some environment, and the inability to fully characterize the environment's state result in a loss of quantum features when looking at the system only (in technical terms, it's a partial trace over an entangled state).

What is wrong with this idea? What is not enough? Why some people are not satisfied with this mechanism?

Alternative ideas involve modifications to the Schrödinger equation, gravity effects, ... Or even more exoteric ideas. These somehow have the advantage of solving the problem of avoiding the problem of a privileged observer.

Comment: Nothing not subjectively wrong.

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just a very pedantic way to explain a completely trivial effect. It's also not enough. Decoherence only works you towards a time scale argument. It never solves the irreversibility issue fully. The much easier way to resolve that 100% in an instant is to go to the relativistic theory.

Answer (score 2):

There has never been a rigorous objection to the idea. (Because it works.)

But that is not enough to convince people. It should be obvious upon hindsight. There is currently no way to know for sure which interpretation is the one true interpretation. We only can rule out completely outlandish interpretations, but leave a huge range of freedom to consider a lot of different interpretations. Whenever you have that, you will not be able to convince everybody that one idea alone is the end-all and be-all. You would not have the smoking gun that other interpretations are straight up wrong. At most you can give other people some evidence that, hey, your idea is not bad, and so please pay some attention.

And then you have a whole bunch of rather philosophically sloppy people who would only stick to the one interpretation they were taught, or they randomly choose to like, and refuse to consider any others. There is never going to be any satisfying those people.

But we have also to be critical of our beloved ideas. One known problem with decoherence is that we would have to explain why the probability of observing stuff accords with the Born rule. There are some work in this direction, but it is not accepted as solved yet.

Comment: *"But we have also to be critical of our beloved ideas. One known problem with decoherence is that we would have to explain why the probability of observing stuff accords with the Born rule."* I'm glad this comment was made as it is really the only thing missing from decoherence.

Comment: There should be more, but it is 2AM and I really need to sleep. Someone else can add more problems.

Comment: It only works because we are making an implicit short term approximation. We are basically taking the easy way out of the problem the same way we do it in statistical mechanics to get around the Poincare recurrence theorem. This is nothing more than the QM version of that. It's also completely unnecessary. In a relativistic universe irreversibility not only comes for free, it's completely unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons people are not satisfied with decoherence are philosophical. If you accept that quantum theory applies to all physical systems, including detectors, human beings and so on, then all of those systems exist in multiple versions:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033

This is commonly called the many worlds interpretation of quantum theory (MWI). The other interpretations either modify quantum theory, e.g. - collapse theories like GRW, or simply refuse to discuss reality like the statistical intepretation. Decoherence suppresses interference between those multiple versions on the scale of everyday life. But this suppression isn't complete and it doesn't imply that the objects we see in everyday life are actually made up of classical point particles that exist only in a single version:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189

https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0149

As a result, people who want the world to look like classical physics and dislike the existence of other universes aren't satisfied with decoherence.

Various reasons are given for this rejection. For example, some critics claim that the MWI doesn't predict the right probabilities:

https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0624

For a criticism of this position see:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02048

For a survey of decoherence with references to criticisms of using it to solve the measurement problem, see:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0312059

Comment: The notion of multiple universes is not required for decoherence. It merely requires superpositions of all the basis functions that make up the Hilbert space.